# Когда и в связи с чем твёрдый знак снова появился в печати?

Tags: орфография, история, апостроф, буква

Недавно копался в архиве и заметил, что во всей периодике 20-30-х годов вместо "ъ" ставили апостроф: "под'езд", "ад'ютант" и т. д. В сороковых — опять всюду твёрдый знак. Если время появления апострофа удалось определить сравнительно точно, 1918 год, то с окончанием периода без ера несколько сложнее, так как материала для оценки было маловато. Может, кто-то тут знает?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Википедия не совсем точна. По поводу изъятия из касс литер с ером (и прочим тяжелым наследием) - все точно. А вот дальше...

Твердого знака в качестве разделителя никто официально не отменял.
Замена его на апостроф была своего рода самодеятельностью, хотя, видимо, и не лишенной некоторых объективных мотивов. На этот счет существуют разные мнения: то ли ер олицетворял старый строй, то ли наборщики путались в типографиях, по старой памяти лепя ер в конце слов...  Ну это помимо того, на что Вики намекает.
Дело в том, что из пяти отменённых реформой 18-го года букв только ер отменялся "не до конца".

В конце двадцатых всякую самодеятельность стали пресекать, упомянутые решения Наркомпроса действительно был направлены на наведение порядка. 
Но! Апостроф какое-то время сохранялся невзирая на все указы.
Это было связано со многими причинами, в числе прочего - работа по созданию новой русской письменности. Именно письменности, там одной орфографией дело не ограничивалось, предлагалось значительно поменять и состав алфавита и некоторые принципы письма. В тридцатых на этой работе решительно поставили крест - а заодно и окончательно вернули орфографию в законное русло: по состоянию на 18-й год.

Answer (score 7):

В Википедии большая статья на эту тему: " При проведении реформы ( русского правописания в 1917—1918гг.) буква Ъ в качестве разделительного знака сохранялась; но для борьбы с издателями газет и журналов, не желавшими подчиняться распоряжениям новой власти, декретом ВСНХ от 4 ноября 1918 года литеры и матрицы буквы были изъяты из типографских касс. В результате в качестве разделительного знака распространилось суррогатное обозначение с помощью апострофа (под’ём, ад’ютант); такое написание стало восприниматься как часть реформы, хотя на самом деле с точки зрения декрета оно являлось ошибочным. Одно время (в конце 1920-х — начале 1930-х) оно распространилось и на книгоиздание, а в машинописи продержалось практически до нашего времени (для экономии числа клавиш дешёвые пишущие машинки делались без Ъ).

В августе 1928 года Наркомпрос признал несвойственным русской грамматике использование апострофа в середине слова вместо буквы «твёрдый знак»..." 
  В дальнейшем устоялся современный вариант и правила написания ъ.

Comment: Из материала статьи следует, что официально апостроф "попал в опалу" в 1928г, но мог появляться и в более позднее время, если текст был набран на дешевой машинке ( без клавиши "Ъ")

Comment: такое написание с апострофом (об'явление) до 70-х сохранилось у машинисток

Comment: Вики перед тем как задать вопрос, я прочитал. Не думаю, что "Известия" печатали на дешёвых машинках, да и в самой статье пишется о том, что именно в конце 20-х- начале 30-х годов начали издавать книги с апострофом, что девальвирует ссылку на Наркомпрос.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, эту ссылку. Может, конечно, вы  эту статью читали. http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/28_632 Там написано, что апостроф постепенно исчезал из печати. "Ъ" узаконен орфографическим сводом 1956г. Поэтому апостроф  встречается до 50-х гг. Но и позже у "ъ" были трудности.
   Кстати, сейчас часто можно увидеть в сообщениях, написанных с айфона,  апостроф вместо ъ. Это связано с тем, что в русской клавиатуре айфонов не сразу можно найти ъ ( и букву ё тоже). Надо удерживать кнопку "ь", тогда появится и ъ, как вариант. Кто не знает об этом, пишет апостроф

Comment: @Надюшка, спасибо за информацию. Я до сих пор использовала орфографические подсказки для вставки Ъ. 
Что касается основного вопроса, смутно помню, что встречала-таки написание с апострофом, кажется, в каких-то объявлениях на стенах. Они были явно не на машинке, буквы крупные. Но подробностей не помню, более 40 лет прошло...